# How to restore view dismissed with SwipeDismissBehavior

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I am using SwipeDismissBehavior for InputTextLayout in CoordinatorLayout.
After it dismiss I need to get it back.
Here is the code how I'm trying to implement this:

```
layoutDateComplete = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDateComplete);
behavior = getSwipeDismissBehavior();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) layoutDateComplete.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(behavior);

private SwipeDismissBehavior<TextInputLayout> getSwipeDismissBehavior() {
SwipeDismissBehavior<TextInputLayout> behavior = new SwipeDismissBehavior();
behavior.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDismissBehavior.SWIPE_DIRECTION_END_TO_START);
behavior.setListener(new SwipeDismissBehavior.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(View view) {
        ViewCompat.setX(layoutDateComplete, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDragStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
return behavior;
```

It is working for the first time. But after the view is not swiping any more.
What is the right way to restore the view after dismissing?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628598/6923440) answer by CI Apps worked almost perfect for me, but the child view did not reappear after I swiped to the right. You can solve this by calling

```
MyChildView.setAlpha(1.0f);
```

So this works to reset the child view:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams tParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) tChild.getLayoutParams();
tParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
tChild.requestLayout();
tChild.setAlpha(1.0f);
```

Alternative way: You can also assign a new `SwipeDismissBehavior` to the `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` to reset the behaviour. You still need to call `setAlpha(1.0f)` on the child after that.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do this.
The following code in **onDismiss** is working pretty well:

```
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(View view) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```